# add a dynamic header to all requests

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I need to add dynamic headers to all requests, but I don't know howto do it.

I started thinking about `requestWillFetch` function of a custom plugin, so I started writing this code:

```
var myPlugin = (function () {
    'use strict';

    const myPlugin = {
        requestWillFetch: async ({request}) => {
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + my_dynamic_token);

            return new Request(request, {
                headers: myHeaders
            });
        }
    };

    return mysteryPlugin;
}());

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('.*'),
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
        plugins: [
            mysteryPlugin,
        ]
    })
);
```

The problem is the variable `my_dynamic_token`, that I do not know howto pass to the service worker.
Right now I have a `window.token` variable in the page, but I read the the window and service worker don't communicate each other.

Comment: Probably not important (typo): in your snippet Workbox would receive `plugins: [undefined]` because in scope is `myPlugin`, not `mysteryPlugin`.

Answer (score 0):

Two viable options come to mind for that:

1. using the `postMessage` method to relay messages between SW and Clients
2. using the browers storage (localStorage, indexedDB)

The first option is easy to implement and probably more suited if you only really need to send the token.

Basically what you need is to have an event listener on the `message` event in your service worker and then process things sent by the client (window) there.

The Service Worker Cookbook by Mozilla has a straight forward detailed example how to implement that: https://serviceworke.rs/message-relay.html

Also reading the API reference can be a good thing to do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage